# What does : mean?

Tags: c++, syntax

I have 2 classes:

```
class base {
    virtual void foo() {};
};

class derived : public base {
    void foo() { base::foo(); }
};
```

I made a mistake and wrote `base:foo();` instead of `base::foo();`. The code was compiled and run, but segfaulted.

I don't know how I can Google it and don't know what it is, but I'm very interested: what does that mean?

```
base:foo();
```

If it is important:

```
class base : public QAbstractGraphicsShapeItem
```

Comment: It's a [label](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/goto).

Comment: This is a case where turning on warnings helps, see [it live](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/ey2lvaSxYPlkjsXG) ... `warning: label 'base' defined but not used [-Wunused-label]` ... perhaps we need to add this ask a question page: *Have you tried turning on warnings*

Comment: That ended with a stack overflow. How appropriate!

Answer (score 125, accepted):

```
void foo() { base:foo(); }
```

is equivalent to:

```
void foo()
{
   base: // An unused label.
   foo(); // Calls the function again, resulting in infinite recursion.
}
```

Due to infinite recursion, the function causes stack overflow.

Comment: yes, i found that mistake when I saw many calls of `foo()` in call stack. thanks

Comment: are there warnings for this available in gcc/clang etc.?

Comment: @Serthy, When I use `-Wall`, I get the warning message: *socc.cc:3:4: warning: label ‘base’ defined but not used [-Wunused-label]
    base: // An unused label.*

Comment: @Serthy: IIRC Visual Studio has the warning " recursive on all control paths" for this.